# Best way to encode/decode large quantities of data for a JavaScript client?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a standalone javascript application with Spine, Node.js, etc.([Here is an earlier incarnation](http://numerology.pinedesk.biz/) of it if you are interested). Basically, the application is an interactive 'number property' explorer. The idea being that you can select any number, and see what properties it possesses. Is it a prime, or triangular, etc? Where are other numbers that share the same properties? That kind of thing.

At the moment I can pretty easily show like numbers 1-10k, but I would like to show properties for numbers 1-million, or even better 1-billion.

I want my client to download a set of static data files, and then use them to present the information to the user. I don't want to write a server backend.

Currently I'm using JSON for the data files. For some data, I know a simple algorithm to derive the information I'm looking for on the client side, and I use that (ie, is it even?). For the harder numbers, I pre compute them, and then store the values in JSON parseable data files. I've kinda gone a little overboard with the whole thing - [I implemented](https://github.com/dsummersl/bloomfilters) a pure javascript [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) and when that didn't scale to 1 million for primes, I tried using [CONCISE bitmaps](http://ricerca.mat.uniroma3.it/users/colanton/concise.html) underneath (which didn't help). Eventually I realized that it doesn't matter too much how 'compressed' I get my data, if I'm representing it as JSON.

So the question is - I want to display 30 properties for each number, and I want to show a million numbers...thats like 30 million data points. I want the javascript app to download this data and present it to the user, but I don't want the user to have to download megabytes of information to use the app...

What options do I have for efficiently sending these large sets of data to my javascript only solution?

Can I convert to binary and then read binary on the client side? Examples, please!

Comment: Thanks all, I'm going to persue the 'compute it on the client' solution. I think its probably the least painful. Thanks so much for the advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just **computing these data points on the client**?

You'll save yourself a lot of headache. You can pre-compute the index chart and leave the rest of the data-points to be processed only when the user selects a particular number.

For the *properties exhibited per number*. Pure JavaScript on modern desktops is blindingly fast (if you stay away from DOM), I think you'll find processing speed differences are negligible between the algorithmic vs pre-computed JSON solution and you'll be saving yourself a lot of pain and unnecessary bandwith usage.

As for the initial index chart, this displays only the *number of properties* per number and can be transferred as an array:

```
'[18,12,9,11,9,7,8,2,6,1,4, ...]'
```

or in JSON:

```
{"i": [18,12,9,11,9,7,8,2,6,1,4, ...]}
```

Note that this works the same for a logarithmic scale since either way you can only attach a value to 1 point in the screen at any one time. You just have to cater the contents of the array accordingly (by returning logarithmic values sequentially on a 1-2K sized array).

You can even use a DEFLATE algorithm to compress it further, but since you can only display a limited amount of numbers on screen (<1-2K pixels on desktop), I would recommend you create your solution around this fact, for example by checking if you can calculate 2K *30 = 60K properties on the go with minimal impact, which will probably be faster than asking the server at this point to give you some JSON.

**UPDATE 10-Jan-2012**

I just saw your comment about users being able to click on a particular property and get a list of numbers that display that property.

I think the intial transfer of number of properties above can be jazzed up to include all properties in the initial payload, bearing in mind that you only want to transfer the values for numbers displayed in the initial logarithmic scale you wish to display (that means that you can skip numbers if they are not going to be represented on screen when a user first loads the page or clicks on a property). Anything beyond the initial payload can be calculated on the client.

```
{ 
  "n": [18,12,9,11,9,7,8,2,6,1,4, ...] // number of properties x 1-2K
  "p": [1,2,3,5,7,13,...] // prime numbers x 1-2K
  "f": [1,2,6, ...] // factorials x 1-2K
}
```

My guess is that a JSON object like this will be around 30-60K, but you can further reduce this by removing properties whose algorithms are not recursive and letting the client calculate those locally.

If you want an alternative way to compress those arrays when you get to large numbers, you can format your array as a VECTOR instead of a list of numbers, storing *differences between one number and the next*, this will keep space down when you are dealing with large numbers (>1000). An example of the JSON above using vectors would be as follows:

```
{ 
  "n": [18,-6,-3,2,-2,-2,1,-6,4,-5,-1, ...] // vectorised no of properties x 1-2K
  "p": [1,1,2,2,2,6,...] // vectorised prime numbers x 1-2K
  "f": [1,1,4, ...] // vectorised factorials x 1-2K
}
```

Comment: I definitely see your point, and for a significant amount of the information I think I can do that while still hitting all the goals I want to hit. But, the point remains - there is a significant amount of data that I need to have available. When that is the case, what do I do?

Comment: How many numbers do you intend to show on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Currently there are two linear scales on screen (one micro the other macro) - I'm planning on replacing the macro one with a logarithmic scale that would show 'all numbers'. I'm thinking I will segment the logarithmic scale and provide summed values for each segment for the various categories. I think that'd be pretty expensive to compute 'in client' as the user selects different properties/numbers.

Comment: The interactive aspect (you can click on multiple properties boxes below to filter by them) of the chart requires that one know the individual properties for each number, so beyond the initial setup, it is not sufficient to have the # of properties per number. But your initial point is taken: 'save yourself some headache'. It literally takes < 2 seconds to computer the primes from 1-million. I'm going to persue that avenue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would say the easiest way would be to break the dataset out into multiple data files. The "client" can then download the files as-needed based on what number(s) the user is looking for.

One advantage of this is that you can tune the size of the data files  as you see fit, from one number per file up to all of the numbers in one file. The client only has to know how to pick the file it's numbers are in. This does require there to be *some* server, but all it needs to do is serve out the static data files.

To reduce the data load, you can also cache the data files using local storage within the browser.

Comment: I can definitely break them up - definitely sensible. Honestly, its probably the quickest way to 'move on' to just implementing the app. Although I'd like to think there was some better way of handling this data than the way I am...

Comment: The two main options I can see would be to either load it "on demand" or to calculate it "on the fly". In either case, if there simply _needs_ to be a lot of data moved to the client, then there isn't much of a way around that. Gzip compression is likely to help _a lot_ in this case, since the data is all text, so you may not have as much of a need to worry as you think. Try it one way, see how it performs, and if it isn't good enough, try again.

Comment: Yes, I suppose lossless *something* makes sense. I see... https://github.com/nmrugg/LZMA-JS I'll have to do some more looking...